# WordPress meta_query not working

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I am having issues with a meta query on a custom post type.

The following arguments are set:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'wp_comp_entries',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => 'wp_comp_entry_competition-id',
                'value'   => $_POST['competition-id'],
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'wp_comp_entry_email',
                'value'   => $_POST['email'],
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
    );
```

A print_r of this looks like:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => wp_comp_entries
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => wp_comp_entry_competition-id
                    [value] => 972
                    [compare] => =
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => wp_comp_entry_email
                    [value] => example@example.com
                    [compare] => =
                )

        )

)
```

Which is great. I then run

```
$lookup = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The start of a print_r of $lookup looks like:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => wp_comp_entries
            [posts_per_page] => -1
            [meta_query] => Array
                (
                )
```

As you can see the meta_query is empty. I have no idea what is causing this as at the bottom of that dump there is this:

```
[query] => Array
(
    [post_type] => wp_comp_entries
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => wp_comp_entry_competition-id
                    [value] => 972
                    [compare] => =
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => wp_comp_entry_email
                    [value] => example@example.com
                    [compare] => =
                )

        )

)
```

Which shows that my code is recognised, WP just isn't feeding it into it's query. I am lost and looking for any direction on why this could not be working?

-- EDIT --

I must add I have tried the standard query from the Codex with no joy either.

Comment: I don't see anythin wrong. Can you check that the entry with that meta keys and meta values exists?

Comment: In the `print_r` output of `$lookup` the WP_Query object, look for the `request` property and post it here. That's the MySQL statement itself, it should tell us more.

Comment: @SeventhSteel

`[request] => SELECT   sosen_posts.* FROM sosen_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND sosen_posts.post_type = 'wp_comp_entries' AND (sosen_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR sosen_posts.post_status = 'future' OR sosen_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR sosen_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR sosen_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY sosen_posts.post_date DESC 
`

Comment: @cybmeta yes there are entries with the meta details. The query returns all posts as there is no other filter. If I use the single filter i.e. use `meta_key =` etc then it works but I need to filter on two meta keys.

Comment: Looks like it's stripping out the entire meta query for some reason. It might be choking on the hyphen in `wp_comp_entry_competition-id`? Try it without that part.

Comment: @SeventhSteel yea it's stripping it out. Like I said in the OP it strips it out no matter what I put in there.

For completenesses sake I tried it without the one with the hyphen. Still no joy.

Comment: @SeventhSteel Weirdly if I change the post type to post the query is passed. Obviously it doesn't work but it shows in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have made a basic error here.

I have hooked into parse_query and made the array blank if certain paramenters are met, which they where here.

Thanks for your help guys, you led me to where to look.

Comment: So, your problem was that you was stripping the `meta_query` in `pare_query` hook? If you need help making the hook working for the main query but not for secondary queries, let us know.